# How to include check boxes in list view using jQuery Mobile?

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I need to display the status of every user with three different levels. So I have a list view of all users. I need to display the status of 3 levels (either attend or not). But I am unable to do that. Can any one help me how can I do similar to following image?[image]

I am getting check box below the name. But I need at right corner which I have drawn with blue color.

Code:

```
 <ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true"  style="margin-right : 5px;margin-left : 5px" id="progress_list" data-filter-placeholder="Filter Names" >
<li data-icon="false"  class="listitem"><a href="#" onClick='#'>Jashwin <input type="checkbox" name="submt_photo" id="submt_photo" class="custom" checked ><input type="checkbox" name="submt_Identity" id="submt_Identity" class="custom" ><input type="checkbox" name="submt_Address" id="submt_Address" class="custom" checked ></a></li>
    </ul>
```

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/manjunath_r/eh6o90gp/

It will be very appreciate if any one let me know how to give different colors of each check box.

Comment: Looks like there's a `position: absolute;` on `.ui-checkbox input, .ui-radio input` causing them to stack ontop of one another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there's a `position: absolute;` on `.ui-checkbox input, .ui-radio input` causing them to stack on top of one another. Here's a version with them side by side http://jsfiddle.net/kdur163h/.

If you have access to the actual markup - you could adjust it like so to have the inputs moved. http://jsfiddle.net/9dygszh4/ ( Wrapped the User's name in a `span` to float them to the left, because floating the inputs would reverse the order. )

Comment: I need the same. But I am able to see only two check boxes from this link http://jsfiddle.net/9dygszh4/

Comment: One of them isn't checked so it's kind of hard to see with this scheme. Might also be some extra CSS style unchecked inputs that's not included? How about this one - http://jsfiddle.net/3q4o6ztt/

Answer (score 0):

If you want the checkboxes to have the jQM look and feel, you could do something like this:

> Here is **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/bpv4kown/1/)** showing both options

For a controlgroup look

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" id="progress_list" data-filter-placeholder="Filter Names" class="has-right-radio">
    <li data-icon="false" class="listitem"> 
        <a href="#" onClick='#' class="ui-btn">Jashwin</a>
        <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" data-mini="true" class="right-radio">
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="submt_photo" id="submt_photo" class="custom" checked /> A</label>
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="submt_Identity" id="submt_Identity" class="custom" />B</label>
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="submt_Address" id="submt_Address" class="custom" checked />C</label>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>

.has-right-radio a {
    padding-right: 124px !important;
}
.right-radio {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    width: 112px;
}
.right-radio .ui-checkbox input {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

If you prefer individual checkboxes instead of toggle buttons:

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" id="progress_list2" data-filter-placeholder="Filter Names" class="has-right-radio">
    <li data-icon="false" class="listitem"> 
        <a href="#" onClick='#' class="ui-btn">Jashwin</a>
        <div  class="right-radio">
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="submt_photo" id="submt_photo" class="custom" checked />&nbsp;</label>
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="submt_Identity" id="submt_Identity" class="custom" />&nbsp;</label>               
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="submt_Address" id="submt_Address" class="custom" checked />&nbsp;</label>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>

#progress_list2 .has-right-radio a {
    padding-right: 132px !important;
}
#progress_list2 .right-radio {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    width: 120px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204);
}

#progress_list2 .right-radio .ui-checkbox {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
#progress_list2 .right-radio .ui-checkbox label {
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 36px;
    border:0;
    border-radius: 0;
}
```